# VS 2017 does not perform the fast up-to-date check if shared bin directory is used for local builds

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

We want to use the shared bin directory for local development builds similarly to how it is used on the CI server. This way a fully built branch of our application occupies less than one third of the space. Which means more branches can fit on our small SSDs.

So, we did that and it all works fine, except VS 2017 IDE no longer uses the fast up-to-date check heuristics.

So, before the change when we built the code the second time the build output reported something like this:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 94 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Meaning IDE employed the heuristic, decided that all the projects are up-to-date (very fast) and skipped msbuild entirely.

After the change, this does not happen, IDE actually hands off all the projects to msbuild, which takes about a minute to burn through all the projects. It does not actually compile any code, but the whole process takes longer now.

It is as if we have set the `DisableFastUpToDateCheck` msbuild property, except that we have not.

So, how do we troubleshoot it? I want the heuristic back.

**EDIT 1**

I owe a few words on how we did it. Every project imports a special targets file just before importing the standard targets (like Microsoft.CSharp.targets). This was developed in the pre MSBuild 15 days, so we do not use `Directory.Build.targets`. In this file we have `OutDir` explicitly set to some shared bin directory within the workspace. So, all the projects specify `OutputPath` as usual, but it is overridden with the `OutDir` in this special targets file. I think this is the root cause for losing the heuristic - it only looks at the csproj, so it sees `OutputPath`, but not `OutDir`. And since no binaries are found at `OutputPath` the heuristic is not satisfied.

I will test this hypethesis and if it turns out to be true will repost this comment as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases when binary log is useless, because it is produced by msbuild, i.e. too late. One has to turn the diagnostics build in Visual Studio, because the first line of it would be from the Heuristic. It specifies the reason why the project is built. All the rest of the diagnostics log can be discarded, but the first line is priceless. It has guided me to the following solution:

**Enabling the Heuristic**

I added the following targets to the targets file we import from every project. Those who do not care about backwards compatibility with MSBuild 14 can add it to Directory.Build.Targets:

*** WE PICKED ANOTHER WAY AT THE END - SEE EDIT 2 ***

```
<Target Name="SatisfyVisualStudioFastUpToDateCheckHeuristic" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(OutDir)' != '' And '$(GatedCheckIn)' != True">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Files Include="$(TargetFileName).config" Condition="'$(AppConfig)' != '' And Exists('$(AppConfig)')" />
        <Files Include="$(TargetName).pdb" />
        <Files Include="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
        <Files Include="@(IntermediateAssembly->'%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
        <Files Include="$(_SGenDllName)" Condition="'$(_SGenDllCreated)'=='true'" />
        <Files Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
        <Files Include="@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory->'%(TargetPath)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)\%(Files.RelativeDir)" />
    <Touch Files="@(Files->'$(OutputPath)%(Identity)')" AlwaysCreate="true" ContinueOnError="true"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="CleanFakeOutputFiles" AfterTargets="AfterClean" Condition="'$(OutDir)' != '' And '$(GatedCheckIn)' != True">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

This target creates zero length fake surrogate output files in the location expected by the heuristic.

**Subsequent action 1**

Doing so may actually fail the build, if one has projects referencing other projects as DLLs rather than as project references. For instance, if the project Alice references the project Bob like this:

```
<Reference Include="Bob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Bob\bin\$(Configuration)\Bob.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The problem is with the `HintPath`. When we build with a shared bin and without the fake surrogate outputs, the `HintPath` is ignored, because it does not lead to any existing file. So, Bob.dll would be found in the shared bin directory and loaded from there. But, when there are fakes in `bin\$(Configuration)` to satisfy the heuristic, the `HintPath` returns an existing file, so the search for Bob.dll ends with the zero length fake. Obviously, compilation would fail. The fix is to either change it to the respective project reference or eliminate the `HintPath` with all the metadata:

```
<Reference Include="Bob" />
```

One has to reference Bob.dll just like we reference system dependencies from the GAC.

**Subsequent action 2**

At this point the code should build and the Heuristic works. Except sometimes it would tell that it cannot find some dependency, like `System.IO.dll`. In this case one has to check if the following two conditions hold:

1. The project references `System.IO.dll` from some directory, like the NuGet packages.
2. `System.IO.dll` is found in the GAC and is a better match for the target framework.

In my case I had several projects referencing `System.IO*`, `System.Runtime*`, `System.Security*` and `System.ValueTuple` from NuGet whereas these dlls exist in the GAC by virtue of having .NET 4.7.2 runtime on the system. The Heuristic looks at the `HintPath` for these references and expects to find them in the `bin\$(Configuration)` folder.

However, the build actually takes them from GAC and the dlls referenced from GAC are not copied by default to the target bin. Therefore there are no fake surrogates to satisfy the Heuristic.

My solution was to replace all these NuGet references with the respective references from the GAC.

**EDIT 1**

**Issues 1**

The side effect of the **subsequent action 1** is that it is no longer easy to go back to local bin folders, because the change to the project dll references is not backwards compatible.

It is possible to keep the `HintPath` metadata, but all of them must point to the shared bin directory, in which case it is still incompatible with the old way.

**Issue 2**

Visual Studio overwrites `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` every time a web application project is loaded. Which means:

- When solution is open
- When the project is unloaded, then reloaded

This is a major bummer, because part of the shared bin approach is to update the paths in `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` through scripting. But this behaviour of VS makes it a major nuisance.

**EDIT 2**

We have changed the way we enable the heuristic. Instead of generating bogus files where VS expects we do the following:

1. Early in the build generate a junction **bin.link --> bin**
2. Set **OutDir = bin.link** in the targets file hidden from the Heuristic
3. Modified all the projects with **OutputPath = bin**

This way the Heuristic sees the right location (OutputPath), but at the same time **OutputPath != OutDir** and so the publishing code works correctly.

So, no more zero length garbage files.

As for the VS overwriting the .vs\config\applicationhost.config - we created a custom VS extension for that.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you could consider [marking it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help members with similar issues. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

> Just to add some details about `I want the heuristic back`.

1.Hmm, just did some tests and confirmed that your `Edit1` is correct.

We can simply reproduce the same issue in local machine without using shared folder. If we use `$(OutDir)` in imported targets, since VS will always look for `$(OutputPath)`, it affects the normal build behavior. (Agree with your Edit1, it should be a good answer!)

2.To resolve the issue, we must avoid using `$(OutDir)` to specify the final output path. So can we use `$(OutputPath)`, sadly **No**!

The `$(OutputPath)` in project file will always override the same-name `$(OutputPath)` defined in imported `xx.targets` file. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#environment-properties): *If the project contains a property definition that has the same name as an environment property, the property in the project overrides the value of the environment variable.*.

The only possible way I can imagine is that we define `$(CustomPath)`(represents the shared folder) in `xx.targets` file, and modify the all `OutputPath` properties in `xx.csproj` to `<OutputPath>$(CustomPath)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>`. That could be a boring job cause you have almost 100 project files :(

I guess the boring job is hard to avoid unless we give up the shared-folder way. This answer is a bit negative but hope it makes some help...

Comment: I might have a better approach. I will report once I finished testing it.

Comment: Sure! That would be great for sharing your useful info. It will help members with similar situation, feel free to add that as answer to help others:)

Comment: Modifying `<OutputPath>$(CustomPath)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>` will not work. Here is why. When the build starts the standard build targets will see that `OutDir` is not set and make it equal `OutputPath`. But the web application publishing code will no longer publish the web applications, because it uses the condition `'$(OutDir)' != '$(OutputPath)'` to decide whether publishing is needed. Your suggestion will trick it into thinking publishing is not needed. Which is wrong, because with shared bin directory you must publish your web applications, you should not run them from the shared.

Comment: Hmm, i test the situation that only use outputpath in targets file, but it works to publish to the shared folder when using publish button in vs... Maybe I miss something, but i fail to reproduce the issue you mentioned in last comment. Or maybe I need to test with an earlier vs version? Could you share more details so that i can check it:)

Comment: Do this: 1. create a simple web application project. 2. On the command line run `msbuild TheWebProj.sln /p:OutDir=C:\The\Shared\Bin` then see that there is `_PublishedWebSites` folder under `C:\The\Shared\Bin`. 3. Modify the project to set `OutputPath` equal to `C:\The\Shared\Bin`. 4. Delete `C:\The\Shared\Bin` 5. Repeat the command from (2) - do you see the `_PublishedWebSites` folder now?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks for the info to help reproduce :)